# How to enter in jitsi meet room in Picture in Picture mode?

Tags: flutter, jitsi, android-picture-in-picture

```
joinClassWithToken({
  @required final String room, //Room ID
  @required final String serevrUrl, //Server Id
  @required final String subject,
  @required final String token, //Subject of Class
  @required final String type,
  final String displayName, //Display Name of user
  final String userEmail, //Email of user
  final bool audioOnly, //Audio Only Flag
  final bool audioMuted, //Audio Mute Flag
  final bool videoMuted, //Video Mute flag
}) async {
  try {
    Map<FeatureFlagEnum, bool> featureFlags = {
      FeatureFlagEnum.INVITE_ENABLED: false,
      FeatureFlagEnum.IOS_RECORDING_ENABLED: false,
      FeatureFlagEnum.LIVE_STREAMING_ENABLED: false,
      FeatureFlagEnum.RECORDING_ENABLED: false,
      FeatureFlagEnum.MEETING_PASSWORD_ENABLED: false,
      FeatureFlagEnum.ADD_PEOPLE_ENABLED: false,
      FeatureFlagEnum.CALL_INTEGRATION_ENABLED: true,
      FeatureFlagEnum.PIP_ENABLED: true
    };
    var options = JitsiMeetingOptions()
      ..room = room // Required, spaces will be trimmed
      ..serverURL = serevrUrl
      ..subject = subject
      ..userDisplayName = displayName
      ..token = token
      ..audioOnly = audioOnly
      ..audioMuted = audioMuted
      ..videoMuted = videoMuted
      ..featureFlags.addAll(featureFlags);
    print(options.toString());
    JitsiMeet.addListener(JitsiMeetingListener(
      onConferenceJoined: ({message}) => print('Jitsi Call Joined : $message'),
      onError: _errorMessage,
    ));
    await JitsiMeet.joinMeeting(options);
  } catch (error) {
    return Exception(error);
  }
}
```

I am developing a flutter application where I need the jitsi meet screen to start in Picturee in Picture Mode by default. I am currently using the [jitsi_meet](https://pub.dev/packages/jitsi_meet) pub.dev package for using jitsi meet. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You can start the instance with the feature flag, `PIP_ENABLED`. Check out the documentation [here (Feature Flags)](https://github.com/gunschu/jitsi_meet#featureflags) on more precisely how to enable flags.

Comment: @Apealed, i tried that but that but jitsi still starts in full screen. I have edited the question. Check my code, if there is something wrong with it.

Comment: That's strange. I would then recommend opening an issue at the [jitsi_meet repository](https://github.com/gunschu/jitsi_meet/issues) on Github. The team appears to be very responsive! Best of luck.

Comment: Good question... Any solution.

Comment: @abnerh69 , I could'nt find any solution regarding this so i changed the user flow to meet my requirements.

Comment: It will require editing the plugin, though very easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue on how `featureFlag` is set on [JitsiMeetingOptions](https://pub.dev/documentation/jitsi_meet_platform_interface/latest/jitsi_meet_options/JitsiMeetingOptions-class.html). Instead of creating a Map<FeatureFlagEnum, bool> featureFlags, I suggest initializing a FeatureFlag object to modify the config.

```dart
 FeatureFlag featureFlag = FeatureFlag();
```

Then update `featureFlag.pipEnabled`

```dart
featureFlag.pipEnabled = true;
```

and set the featureFlag

```dart
var options = JitsiMeetingOptions()
  ..featureFlag = featureFlag;
```